# 'Guest users cannot be record owners' error during deployment of test class to production

Tags: failing-tests, guest-user

I have increased test coverage of a class in QA Sandbox and I am trying to deploy that test class to production. When I run the test class in QA Sandbox, there is no error. But when I am deploying it to production, I am getting an error `'Guest users cannot be record owners'`.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image: error]

The class has nothing to do with communities. I am not able to understand why I am getting the error in production and not in QA Sandbox.

The version of QA Sandbox and Production is Summer 20. I read that there were some changes in Summer 20 release regarding guest users ([Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_user.htm)). In release notes, there is a section `Automatically Assign Records Created by Guest Users to a Default Owner`. Here is the [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_reassign_guest_records.htm). I verified that this checkbox is checked in both QA and production.

I am not able to find a way to solve this error. I am not able to answer why I am getting the error when the class has nothing to do with communities. Also, why am I getting the error in production and not in QA Sandbox even though class has the same code? Please guide. Thank You!

Comment: looks like they also say to select default owner here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_assign_guest_records.htm&type=5  dont know though if it would be related

Comment: @User6670 Thanks for the suggestion! I will look at the default owners in both the orgs.

Comment: @User6670 The default owner is set for Production and QA Sandbox. Both the users are active. So that should not be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the test class quering users and assigning the ownership of records to the user queried. In your case the system is returing a community user. Change the query to return a particular user profile or insert a new user and use it to assign the record ownership.

Comment: Okay. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: This exactly. I had a unit test fail with this, and added `userType = 'Standard'` to the user select where clause to ensure it always returned a "normal" user.

Comment: @mkdjns Any idea why the setting `Assign new records created by guest users to the default owner` is not working? [More info](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_reassign_guest_records.htm)

Comment: @Koustubh I don't. My specific test case wasn't dealing with records created by a guest user, but was instead reassigning ownership on existing records.

Answer (score 2):

@Koustubh, I ran into this same issue today.  I was deploying a single controller class for a lightning component that had nothing to do with communities and received the same error.  I also already had default owners set for each community and had the community setting enabled to enforce the default owner for records created by guest users.

I "solved" this by disabling the community setting that enforces default owners for records created by guest users.  It seems like this may be a bug as it appears to be doing the exact opposite of what the release notes provide for information.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll try it.