# Test Class Fail - first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception (Guest users cannot be record owners.):

Tags: unit-test, guest-user, field-integrity-exception

I'm getting above error message when I run a test class. This class has nothing to do with Public sites/community. As per the research, I have explicitly added an OwnerId for the record. But still it gives me the same error. Please note that, this doesn't come in other lower sandbox. Only on Production.

```
 @isTest
    static void processSaveRecordTest(){
        
        Test.startTest();
        String uniqueUserName = 'cduser' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '@cd.com';
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='counsellor@cd.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName=uniqueUserName);
        insert u;        
            
            Campaign cm = new Campaign();
            cm.name = 'Test Campaign';
            cm.StartDate = Date.parse( '12/17/2019' );
            cm.OwnerId = u.id;
            insert cm;
            
            List<Lead__c> ldList = new List<Lead__c>();
            Lead__c ld;
            ld = new Lead__c();
            ld.Email__c = 'test@test.com';
            ld.Mobile__c = '1234567890';
            ld.First_Name__c = 'fName';
            ld.Last_Name__c = 'lName';
            ld.Lead_Source__c = 'facebook';
            ld.OwnerId = u.id;                
            ldList.add(ld);
            
            ld = new Lead__c();
            ld.Email__c = 'test@test.com';
            ld.Mobile__c = '1234567890';
            ld.First_Name__c = 'fName';
            ld.Last_Name__c = 'lName';
            ld.Campaign__c = cm.Id;
            ld.Lead_Source__c = 'Call';
            ld.OwnerId = u.id;               
            ldList.add(ld);
            
            
            insert ldList;
        
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: Please check whether this will help you. 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313448/guest-users-cannot-be-record-owners-error-during-deployment-of-test-class-to-p

Comment: Thanks. I saw that. I already create a User and Assign it as an Record Owner. But no luck yet.